# NSTask waitUntilExit is not working as expected

Tags: objective-c

I am using FSEventStreamCreate to monitor the .Trash directory.
My callback function is a static function , which is executed whenever the .Trash changes .

In the callback function i need to run one script to get some status ,through NSTask with NSPipe . When the [ls waitUntillExit] is executed for the first time, function executes from the  start again . The program continues from [ls waitUntillExit] normally when it reaches for the second time . What is the problem in my code. [The code from number 1 to number 2 executes 2 times ]

This is my code  of myCallbackFunction of FSEvent.

```
static void myCallbackFunction(
                           ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                           void *clientCallBackInfo,
                           size_t numEvents,
                           void *eventPaths,
                           const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                           const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[])
{

    ////////////////number 1////////////   
    int i;


    FILE *fp;

    char path[1035];

    /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen("/bin/ls ~/.Trash/POC3.app", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(0);
    }
    i=0;
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        i++;
    }///////if the file POC.app exists in trash execute this//////////////////
    if(i!=0){


        NSTask *ls=[[NSTask alloc]init] ;
        NSPipe *pipe1=[NSPipe pipe];
        NSData *data ;
        NSString *tmpString;

        [ls setStandardOutput:pipe1];
        NSString *execPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"script"];
        [ls setLaunchPath:execPath];
        [ls setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello",nil]];

        [ls launch];
        [ls waitUntilExit];
        ///////////////number 2/////////////////

        data = [[[ls standardOutput] fileHandleForReading] availableData];






        if ((data != nil) && [data length]) {

            tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];




         }

    //some other functionality follows here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a deadlock.  You don't read the output of the script until after the script has exited.  If it blocks because the pipe buffer is full, it will never terminate.